Shift + Tab Backward Navigation Skipping Elements
I'm experiencing an issue with keyboard navigation on my website. When I use the Tab key to navigate forward through interactive elements, everything works as expected (I can tab through <a> element with link_class and <button> element with button class). However, when I try to navigate backward using Shift + Tab, it skip button element and directly go to the <a> element.
<div class="container">
    <a href="link.html" class="link_class">
        <span class="text">
            Layouts
        </span>
    </a>
    <button class="button"></button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="link.html" class="link_class">
        <span class="text">
            Shop
        </span>
    </a>
    <button class="button"></button>
</div>
--SNIP--

Browsers: Chrome, Edge
OS: Windows

What browser, what operating system?

Chrome, Edge, Windows

I tried your code on both Chrome and Edge on Windows and the navigation proceeded as expected through both links and both buttons in reverse order when I used Shift-Tab.
